# How to express $1m in a formal document?

Tags: expressions

I'd like to say something like:

> I helped my company win a $1m deal with customer A.

I'm not sure which one of the following is the best one for a formal document? e.g. in a resume:

*1 million dollar deal*, *$1 million deal*, *1 million$ deal*, or anything better?

Comment: Why not use simply **a million dollar deal**? Not sure you need the **1** when you have **a**.

Comment: it's WIN, not WON.  Also you should be more precise, like "I won a $1.3m deal for the company."

Comment: @JoeBlow, I like the way you say "it's WIN" and then your example uses WON - lol.

Comment: LOL exactly !!!

Comment: But serious Dej, it's "I helped win" or "I won"

Comment: See also [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193246), [that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149190), and [the other](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112248) questions. None are an exact dupe, but you may find them useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Officially, *m* stands for *milli* (which means 10<sup>-3</sup>, i.e. a *thousandth*), and *M* stands for *mega*, that is *million*.
A $5k or a $2M deal would be better.

More formal would be

> *a five thousand dollar deal* or *a $5,000 deal*
>   *a two million dollar deal* or *a $2,000,000 deal*.

I would certainly refrain from mixing text and numbers, especially in formal writing, so I would avoid anything using

> *$2 million, *$5 thousand

Comment: What about `a one million dollar deal`? Is it ok to put `a` and `one` together?

Comment: I see no problem with _a one (million) dollar deal_, as it explicitly shows the deal is worth _on_ million, not _two_ or _three_. Just _a million dollar deal_ means roughly the same, but it feels less precise.

Comment: @oerkelens Why not two or three? **A** in this case has a special meaning, not *one* per se. There is a recent related Q on ELU. I've not yet checked it again.

Comment: @Kris: are you asking why _one_ does not mean _two_? I am making exactly the point you seem to be expressing: _a million dollar deal_ may **not** be about _exactly one million_!

Comment: oerkelens No, I didn't mean such a GR thing, lol, but something else altogether. Anyways, there's a mix up, sorry.

Comment: +1 good clarification about *mille* but perhaps add a parenthetical that it means *thousand*

Comment: @bib: that is _milli_, not **ever** _mille_; the prefix for _thousand_ is K. It means one _thousandth_, not _thousand_. But it's a good point about clarification, I added it.

Comment: the fact is though, it's extremely common to use "m" (not "M") when you're discussing such stuff.  we did 3m this year, that was a 2m deal, etc.

Comment: @JoeBlow: yes, sloppy use of units is indeed incredibly common. That is no reason not to mention that it is sloppy. If you think m is 1 million, good luck with taking 500 mg of paracetamol :) Sloppiness leads to confusion, I often see people having no idea that Mb and MB are not the same unit. But they do wonder why their internet is "slow" when they pay for 10 Mb/s and download at 1 MB/s.

Comment: Hey oerk -- "sloppy use of units is indeed incredibly common"?  Do you think so?  Among scientists, etc, I don't see it so often! To be clear, what I meant in the previous was "in the milieu of venture capitalists, the sewer that is the 'dot-com universe', and the broader deal-making-world generally, but particularly with an emphasis on the current 'technology/internet' era..." .. it is more usual to write 3m, 1m. (And indeed, for salaries, 20k, 80k, etc., also lower-case.)  Sorry if I was unclear on that.

Comment: @JoeBlow: I did mean "among people in the street". I may _hope_ scientists do not mix up _m_ and _M_ when preparing your prescription medicine, the same way they would not mix pounds and Newtons on a Mars mission... [oh wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter).

Comment: lol good one....

Comment: The [SI prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) for 1000 is lowercase `k` (probably for historic reasons) and for 1'000'000 it's uppercase `M`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I stand corrected and note that I exemplified my own point :(

Comment: Folks, cool down. We are not talking about prefixes (milli/mega) **at all,** but a unit all by itself: *m* = million. Go figure!

Answer (score 3):

<strike>1</strike> million dollar deal  —  Use words instead: (a) **one** million dollar deal
$1 million deal — correct, but unidiomatic
1 million$ deal — just plain wrong, currency symbol is not suffixed to words.
$1m deal — correct, but unidiomatic

The options would thus be:

- One million dollar deal — should be okay
- A million dollar deal — idiomatic, preferred in literary/ narrative use
- A $1m deal — use in shortened versions, titles, captions, abstracts …
- A one million dollar deal — uses the idiom, use for effect.

Comment: Note that "a million dollar deal" need not have anything to do with one million or even with dollars.

Comment: A one-million-dollar deal, with a dash.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the corrections may be the following:
***category-1***
"I helped my company winning a million dollars' deal with customer
A."
"I helped my company winning a one million dollars' deal with
customer A."
***category-2***
"I helped my company winning a US$1 million (1M) deal with
customer A."
"I helped my company winning a $1 million (1m) deal with customer
A."
***category-3***
"I helped my company winning a US$1 million deal with customer A."
"I helped my company winning a $1 million deal with customer A."
***category-4***
"I helped my company winning a US$1M deal with customer A."
"I helped my company winning a US$1m deal with customer A."
***category-5***
"I helped my company winning a $1M deal with customer A."
"I helped my company winning a $1m deal with customer A."

All, stated above, are correct; I, on the whole, prefer to use ***category-2/sentence no-1*** .

REFERENCES:
1)https://www.onlinegrammar.com.au/writing-style-tips-how-to-write-about-money/
2)https://www.avidcareerist.com/2014/01/06/how-to-abbreviate-million-on-your-resume/
3)https://www.thebalance.com/write-numbers-using-words-4083198

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Most of the sentences you've written sound quite foreign to me.